# Is there a way to cast "en passant"?

Tags: go, casting

Suppose that the file `token.txt` contains a single string. In order to read it, I have to

```
byteToken, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("token.txt")
token := string(byteToken)
```

Is there a way to "automatically cast" a variable, so that I do not need to use the intermediate case when I know what type I want to use? Something along the lines of (this is invalid code of course)

```
string(token), _ := ioutil.ReadFile("token.txt")
```

---

About the title: *[en passant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant)* is a chess move where something happens when you do something else (the adversary captures your pawn as you move it) - in this case, I wanted to highlight the fact that the casting would be done as the read call is made.

Comment: No, you have to handle error first and then use the other return values. That is the recommended method.

Comment: You can wrap the call to `ioutil.ReadFile` in a function that does the casting, but I'm not sure why that would be better than the code you've already got.

Comment: No, and in such a case I would advise against what you're after: type-conversing a byte slice to a string (Go does not have type casting) copies the source (doing in the other way round copies, too).

Comment: @kostix: could you please elaborate on why this is a bad idea? (the conversion, not the approach to do everything in one step) The token I have in the file must be readable by a human, and later in the code used as a `string`.

Comment: @WoJ: copying. You will double memory usage just to convert a byte slice to a string. If the token is like less than 1k, that's OK but if you'll try to perform the same trick on a file of hefty size, that'll be a bad idea. A correct approach is to write a wrapper to produce a string out of the file, directly. A combination of `strings.Builder` and `io.Copy` could do the trick.

Comment: @kostix there is no such method. `strings.Builder` uses a byte slice internally anyway. Strings in Go are immutable, and all I/O happens in bytes, so there is no way to "produce a string out of the file directly".

Comment: @Adrian, `strings.Builder` knows a dirty trick: when you ask it to hand you out a string, it uses `unsafe` to produce a string out of that byte slice without copying. Otherwise this type would be a bit useless, really ;-)

Comment: This and other recent questions are being discussed (indirectly) on meta.  [Is there some kind of special scrutiny near 20k?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408255).  I don't see any obvious problem with this question, unless this is something that people think should be obvious to anyone who knows any Go syntax.  Perhaps also asking "Or would that be a bad idea even if possible?" would make it possible for an answer to explain the Go philosophy.  (I don't know Go myself, but it certainly seems like a reasonable how-does-Go-do-things question)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a utility function:

```
func ToString(arr []byte, err error) (string, error) {
  if err != nil {
     return "", err
  }
  return string(arr), nil
}

token, err := ToString(ioutil.ReadFile(...))
```

Above, token is a string.